# PHP mySQL UPDATE script wont execute

Tags: php, mysql

I can't understand why this will not be executed into the mySQL database?
Everything is set and all it does is to update some values.

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect(This is filled.);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `members` SET `rank`='$_POST[rank]' WHERE `id`='$_POST[id]'");


mysqli_close($con);
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Heres the thing that should fill the $_POSTs

```
<form action="setrank.php" method="post">
User: 
  <select>
      <?php
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY id");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<option name='id' id='id' value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['username'] . " (" . $row['id'] . ")</option>";
  }
?>
  </select><br />
Set rank to: 
    <select><option name="rank" id="rank" value="0" >Guest.</option><option name="rank" id="rank" value="1" >Moderator.</option><option value="2" name="rank" id="rank">Administrator.</option><option value="3" name="rank" id="rank">Owner.</option></select>
<br /><input type="submit">
</form>
```

Thank you very much for help, i've been using hours. :/

Comment: The `name` attribute belongs on `<select name='rank'>` not on `<option name='rank'>`, same for `id` You should be checking that the form was posted before attempting to do the `UPDATE`, and most importantly, the code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  It is important to [start learning how to use `mysqli::prepare()`](http://us1.php.net/mysqli_prepare) to create prepared statements, safe from SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

The form `select` element define incorrect, add form field `name` in `select box` not an options please try this way

```
<select name="id"> 
 <option value="xyz">Name</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @KinJacob, ok good, if you answer useful then please correct.